# StackOverflowException in solrnet

Tags: solrnet, stack-overflow

We have the same requirement of passing huge data like http://bugsquash.blogspot.in/2010/12/customizing-solrnet.html, we tried the following.

1) Increased the requestHeaderSize to Int32.MaxValue - stackoverflow exception

2) Used PostSolrconnection  - got the StackOverflow exception. 

3) Downloaded the source of solrnet and added as project reference - Stackoverflow exception

 Then even we changed to GET, we are getting the StackOverflow exception. The error is coming when we have more than 500 reference ids. If we have less values, it works.

This is how we are calling,

```
searchResults = solrPost.Query(new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(new[] 
                { 
                    query 
                 }), 
                      new SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.QueryOptions 
                      { 
                          Fields = new[] { "*", "score" }, 
                          Start = pageSize, 
                          Rows = 40, 
                          OrderBy = listSort 
                      });
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

We tried requesting solr using HttpRequest and identified as maxBooleanClause issue and then POST started working through HttpRequest. But using SolrNet the error is occurred and it is happening at serializing the query object. queryserializer.serialize(Query)

Comment: Show the call stacks of the exceptions please.

Comment: Also GitHub fork of the code if available.

Comment: I didn't get any stack trace, it just shows System.StackOverflowException and "No source available". Also this exception arises immediately while executing the above line and i didn't see any solr query in the java console.

Comment: Then use debug version and/or compile it from source. Call stack will greatly help (and it's much easier to debug a StackOverflow than an invalid memory access for example).

Comment: Yes, i tried that. If you refer my point #3, i tried but it is the same error with "No Source".

Comment: You have to try it harder.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why step 2 didn't work which is the exact fix for the long Get request issue, i.e. to switch over to Post request.

Chances are there is an issue with the piece of code where you are initialising SolrNet to use PostSolrConnection instead of the default SolrConnection. Need to look at the bit of code which gets you the instance of solrPost object. Take another look at it and post it here.

Comment: I have identified the issue for the POST, the issue is we have exceeded maxBooleanClause of Solr. After we increased the size in solrconfig.xml, we are getting the results.

Comment: Yes of course first things first, Solr side needs to be configured to accept these long Get requests along with the large number of Boolean clauses (AND, OR, etc).

Comment: The other bit related to Get query length that might hit you next is the app. container (Jetty, Tomcat, etc.) headerBufferSize limit. Here's the solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/136249/how-do-we-increase-the-maximum-allowed-http-get-query-length-in-jetty

We ran through the issue sometime back and patched the Get method of SolrConnection (no longer necessary) as a fix. Here are the details: http://teach-algo.blogspot.in/2013/06/solution-for-making-long-get-request-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the SolrNet didn't work due to stackoverflow error while serializing the query parameters. Alternate workaround is posted http://smartcoder.in/solrnetstackoverflow/

Comment: Can you please summarize the solution here if you are going to link to another site?

Comment: @Sharlike i posted the solution in the site. The solution is to use HttpWebRequest to get the solr results and use SolrNet to get the query parameters and parse the xml results as ISolrResult.